# Ayuda con mensajes de redes lentas

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un caso extremadamente extraño, quien podría ayudarme a solucionarlo, tengo una página web desarrollada en vs2005, hay un front y un back, el back es web service y el front es aspx, el back se conecta a la BD, bueno eso como resumen. Lo extremadamente raro es que en la autentican tengo este código:

```
bool Authenticated = ServicioWeb.validar(txtUser.Text,txtpass.Text);
if (Authenticated)
    {
        Session["Usuario"] = txtUser.Text;
        Response.Redirect("resCambio.aspx", false);            
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "usuario no valido."; 
    }
```

Como podrán observar es bastante simple, lo raro es que si la red desde la que utilizo el sitio web es lenta muestra el mensaje del camino del false, si la red es 4g o superior el usuario puede autenticarse con normalidad, ojo que el back como el front están en el mismo server, pero no entiendo porque se va por el false el redes lentas, el código del método validar del back es bastante simpel solo un select al usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que tanto el sitio con las paginas aspx y el servicio asmx estan bajo el mismo IIS en diferente sitio web

Esta claro que la velocidad de conexion desde el cliente no es el problema ya que esta no afecta como se conecta el aspx con el aspx cuando valida el usuario. Ademas si retorna false quiere decir que el servicio responde.

Podrias en el codigo definir codigo de log a un archivo para ver que camino toma la ejecucion, es mas podrias loguear el StopWatch para ver cuento tarda en responde

Si en el codigo tienes controles de errores con try...catch quitalos para que si hay algun fallo que pudiera cambiar la logica de validacion no se genere y puedas ver en pantalla el problema, con esto se descarta que un exception incorrectamente controlado genere este problema.